# Adding a string to one of my database rows - why is this not working?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database that I am learning SQL with and I am trying to add the string '(Deceased)' next to my pets that have passed away (meaning that a column with 'dead' has value 1. So I do:

```
UPDATE pet 
SET name = str(name) + '(Deceased)' 
WHERE dead = 1;
```

But it doesn't work and I am not sure why. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use concatenation operator `||`:

```
UPDATE pet SET name = name || '(Deceased)' WHERE dead = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the data type in the query ... run the below query and it will store Deceased under your name column where dead=1

```
UPDATE pet SET name = 'Deceased' WHERE dead = 1;
```

plus if there is only one row to update then I suggest you to use `primary key (id)` in the where clause to change the name instead of `dead`. You can do

Answer (score 0):

Use CONCAT Function:

```
UPDATE pet 
SET name = CONCAT( name ,  '(Deceased)')  
WHERE dead = 1;
```